# Are NHibernate projection/DTO objects immutable?

Tags: nhibernate

If I create a DTo using projection and an import mapping, is the object by default then immutable for NHibernate or is it possible to define mutable=false in the import mapping?

Comment: just found out mutable is not an option. But still are the DTO/projection objects added to the Identitymap or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a test that gets the same DTO from NHibernate then checks to see if they are reference equal.  If they are reference equal then I would assume NHibernate keeps them in the identity map.  My guess is that they are not reference equal.

```
ReferenceEquals(dto1, dto2)
```